# SQL - How to Compare Tables and Count Occurrences

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables that I need to compare in SQL using Big Query, tables (A) and (B).

- **Table A** is a full list of all fruit sold by different vendors. Each of the three vendors has three types.
- **Table B** is a list of sales by vendor, and which fruit they sold on each day

```
    (Table A)             (Table B) 
    ID | Fruit     ID |  Item  | Sold | Date
    ---+--------  ----+--------+------+-------        
    1  | Apple     1  | Apple  |  1   |  M
    1  | Orange    1  | Apple  |  1   |  T
    1  | Banana    2  | Orange |  1   |  M
    2  | Apple     2  | Banana |  1   |  W
    2  | Orange    2  | Orange |  1   |  F
    2  | Banana    3  | Banana |  1   |  S
    3  | Apple
    3  | Orange
    3  | Banana
```

What I'm trying to do is join these tables, to create **Table C** where I want it to show me all the vendors and fruit available, as well as how many sold of each type, by vendor, overall. I also want to include any null values as 0 as well.

The tricky part is that the **ITEM** column in Table B is a concatenated field, so I can't immediately join from A where fruit = Item from B, so I assume that I would have to have it be two sub-queries, and result in creating a table C.

```
       (Table C)

    ID | Fruit  | Sold
    ---+--------+-------
    1  | Apple  | 2
    1  | Orange | 0 
    1  | Banana | 0 
    2  | Apple  | 0 
    2  | Orange | 2 
    2  | Banana | 1 
    3  | Apple  | 0 
    3  | Orange | 0 
    3  | Banana | 1
```

Not sure if it's an issue with how I'm joining tables, but I'm just not able to get the results to pan out. I'll absolutely blame it on my novice-level SQL skills though -- so appreciate any guidance on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` with aggregates function `sum` as following

Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mtnebJ1mgABgdQeF3Naqnh/0).

```
select
  a.id,
  a.fruit,
  coalesce(sum(sold), 0) as sold
from tableA a
left join tableB b
on a.id = b.id
and a.fruit = b.item
group by
  a.id,
  a.fruit
```

output:

```
| id  | fruit  | sold |
| --- | ------ | ---- |
| 1   | Apple  | 2    |
| 1   | Banana | 0    |
| 1   | Orange | 0    |
| 2   | Apple  | 0    |
| 2   | Banana | 1    |
| 2   | Orange | 2    |
| 3   | Apple  | 0    |
| 3   | Banana | 1    |
| 3   | Orange | 0    |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL you would make an inner join.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Fruit, B.Sold 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL

SELECT ID, Fruit, IFNULL(Sold, 0) AS Sold
FROM `project.dataset.tableA`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ID, Item AS Fruit, SUM(Sold) AS Sold 
  FROM `project.dataset.tableB`
  GROUP BY ID, Item  
) 
USING(ID, Fruit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL query As Below :

```
SELECT 
     Ta.id
    ,Ta.Fruit
    ,isnull(Tb.Sold,0)Sold 
FROM TableA Ta
    Left join(
        SELECT  
        id ,
        item
        ,sum(Sold)Sold 
        FROM TableB
        GROUP BY id 
        ,item 
    )Tb ON Ta.id=tb.id AND Ta.Fruit=Tb.Item
```